# Where can the ProviderRpcError type be imported from?

Tags: metamask, ethereumjs

I am creating a WalletConnect function in typescript and React.
I want to process when `window.ethereum.request` returns an error, but I can't directly reference the error as being an unknown type.

[image]

It was stated that the request function returns a fixed form of interface on error (ProviderRpcError - https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/reference/provider-api/#errors).

I thought I could import ProviderRpcError, but I cannot find the corresponding package.

How can I implement this so that I can check the `err.code`?